# Three.js infinite loop crash

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a library of 'letter' functions that return letters in vertex coordinates. The goal is to be able to write words/sentences with an interactive PointsCloud. Using TextGeometry does not work as it does not produce enough vertex points.

The W() function adds all the corner points, manually entered.
The Draw() function 'draws' vertex points in between the manually entered points.

The problem I am having is that my code is causing a 'Potential out of Memory error' crash and I am not sure why. Google Chrome is flagging the 'for' loop in the Draw() function as the problem.

```
            function W(int) {
            w = new THREE.Geometry();
            w.vertices.push(
                new THREE.Vector3(-1,1,0),
                new THREE.Vector3(-.5,-1,0),
                new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0),
                new THREE.Vector3(5,-1,0),
                new THREE.Vector3(1,1,0)
            )
            var temp = w;
            for(var u = 0; u < temp.vertices.length; u++){
                Draw(w,int,u,u++)
            }
            return w;
        }

        function Draw(P,intensity, v1, v2)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < intensity; i++){
                var diffX = Math.abs(P.vertices[v1].x - P.vertices[v2].x);
                var spacingX = diffX/intensity;
                if(P.vertices[v1].x-P.vertices[v2].x > 0){spacingX=spacingX*-1}

                var diffY = Math.abs(P.vertices[v1].y - P.vertices[v2].y);
                var spacingY = diffY/intensity;
                if(P.vertices[v1].y-P.vertices[v2].y > 0){spacingY=spacingY*-1}

                var diffZ = Math.abs(P.vertices[v1].z - P.vertices[v2].z);
                var spacingZ = diffZ/intensity;
                if(P.vertices[v1].z-P.vertices[v2].z > 0){spacingZ=spacingZ*-1}

                p = new THREE.Vector3(
                    P.vertices[v1].x+spacingX*i,
                    P.vertices[v1].y+spacingY*i,
                    P.vertices[v1].z+spacingZ*i
                )
                P.vertices.push(p)
            }
        }

        pointCloud = new THREE.Points(W(10), pointMaterial)
        scene.add(pointCloud)
```

Comment: As a small note: `Draw(w,int,u,u++)` will make both arguments `v1` and `v2` be the same number. if you want to increment AND return the incremented value, add the `++` to the left, like so: `Draw(w,int,u,++u)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

The problem was I assigned a variable to an array, which only mirrors the array and does not create a new unique array.

```
  var temp = w;
            for(var u = 0; u < temp.vertices.length; u++){
                Draw(w,int,u,u++)
            }
```

should be...

```
                var temp = w.vertices.length;
            for(var u = 0; u < temp-1; u++){
                Draw(w,int,u,u+1)
            }
```